# CSS: Responsive 3x3 grid messing up on window resize

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to make a responsive 3x3 grid to put my noughts and crosses game on.
It's working for me when I have a maximized screen but as soon as I make the window smaller to check for responsiveness everything messes up.
What's going on? Should I use something other than vh's?
http://codepen.io/apswak/pen/dXdjvW

```
<h3>Noughts and Crosses</h3>
<div class="gameGrid">
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
</div>
```

style.css

```
body {
  background-color: wheat;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.gameGrid {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 62vh;
  height: 62vh;
}

.cell {
  margin-bottom: -5px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 18.82vh;
  height: 18.82vh;
  border: 5px solid green;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: You should set up your `.cell` width to percentages instead of vh since your parent `.gameGrid` already use it and it might break the width inheritance.

Comment: what type of messing is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd probably take the [flexbox](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp) route. I've kept your gameGrid class but added a row class and inside each row, I've added 3 cells. Don't worry about the [naming](http://getbem.com/naming/) unless you want to.

```css
.gameGrid {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 62vh;
  height: 62vh;
  background: green;
}
.gameGrid--row {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.gameGrid--cell {
  background: blue;
  margin: 5px;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
.gameGrid--cell:before {
  content: '';
  float: left;
  padding-top: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="gameGrid">
  <div class="gameGrid--row">
    <div class="gameGrid--cell"></div>
    <div class="gameGrid--cell"></div>
    <div class="gameGrid--cell"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gameGrid--row">
    <div class="gameGrid--cell"></div>
    <div class="gameGrid--cell"></div>
    <div class="gameGrid--cell"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="gameGrid--row">
    <div class="gameGrid--cell"></div>
    <div class="gameGrid--cell"></div>
    <div class="gameGrid--cell"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```